# Get Integer list from one file

Tags: java, string, list, integer, contain

This script checks skills from the config file and allows using only them (in order stop hacking).

Here is the process of how to work my script works:

**#1** There is special .ini configuration file with this skill list:

```
CommunityAvailableBuffs = 11517,11522;
```

**#2** File config.java gets a list from the config file and convert to the integer:

```
public static List<Integer> COMMUNITY_AVAILABLE_BUFFS;

final String[] allowedBuffs = 
CommunityBoard.getString("CommunityAvailableBuffs", "").split(",");
COMMUNITY_AVAILABLE_BUFFS = new ArrayList<>(allowedBuffs.length);
    for (String s : allowedBuffs)
    {
        COMMUNITY_AVAILABLE_BUFFS.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
    }
```

**#3** File `HomeBoard.java` get this list from config.java file and check skills from this list.

```
if (!Config.COMMUNITY_AVAILABLE_BUFFS.contains(skill.getId()))
{
    continue;
}
```

---

My question is how to paste skill list directly in HomeBoard.java file without using config and config.java files, I tried to use something like this:

```
List<Integer> allallowedBuffs = "11517,11522";
final String[] allowedBuffs = CommunityBoard.getString(allallowedBuffs, "").split(",");
allallowedBuffs = new ArrayList<>(allowedBuffs.length);
for (String s : allowedBuffs)
{
    allallowedBuffs.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
}

if (!allowedBuffsend.contains(skill.getId()))
{
    continue;
}
```

But unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: what is not working?

Comment: `"11517,11522"` is a String not a List of Integer

Comment: Yes, console gave me this error:

 List<Integer> allallowedBuffs = "11517,11522";
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to List<Integer>

Comment: you could simply create the list and add elemnts to it; List<Integer> aab = new ArrayList<>(); list.add(11517);

Answer (score 2):

If i understand your question correctly you can simply use following line to fill `allallowedBuffs` with some hardcoded data.

```
List<Integer> allallowedBuffs = Arrays.asList(11517,11522);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem has been solved!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, if it is Java8

```
List<Integer> allallowedBuffs = List.of(11517, 11522);
```